# Installing Fritz Wireless USB Adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, internet, adapter

How do I install a Fritz USB wireless adapter on Ubuntu so I can access the internet? I have the software required, but I am not sure what to do next. Ubuntu version 13.04.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
don@don-MS-7327:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 057c:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:2101 Dell Computer Corp. SmartCard Reader Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
don@don-MS-7327:~$
```

What do I do next?

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the output of `lsusb`? Also, the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Ubuntu version 13.4, Where can I find the output of lsusb?

Comment: Open the terminal (either pressing Ctrl + Alt + T; or Alt + F2 then typing `gnome-terminal`, enter) and type `lsusb` then enter, edit your post and add the results.

Comment: Result: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 057c:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]

Comment: What do I do next?

Comment: You do absolutely nothing!  The driver has been recognized and is available... ;)
You might answer your own question and mark it as solved so that other people don' come looking for "unanswered" questions...